# ¿Cómo hacer que no se inserte el mismo registro varias veces?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con `Visual Studio 2017` en `C#`, y me surgió una duda, como puedo hacer que no se inserte un registro mas de una vez, tengo el siguiente cogido:

```
private void MeterProgramas()
    {            
        programa_cortadorTableAdapter.Fill(galaxyfxDataSet.programa_cortador);
        if (dgvCortadores.RowCount == 0)
        {
            var res = acc.EjecutarSELECT("SELECT * FROM galaxyfx_produccion.infolote WHERE (Status = 'NO PAGADO') AND (Autorizado = 1)");                
            foreach (DataRow row in res.Rows)
            {
                acc.EjecutarINSERT("INSERT INTO programa_cortador(Programa) VALUES(" + Convert.ToInt32(row["Programa"]) + ")");
            }
        }
        dgvCortadores.BestFitColumns();
    }
```

Lo que hago es que primero consulto una tabla y después inserto los datos del campo de Programa, en otra, y hago que se ejecute cada vez que se abre el `windows form`, pero no quiero que se repitan los programas, los datos los muestro en un `gridControl` de `devexpress`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siguiendo tu codigo, podrias cambiar el select, para que te traiga los datos que no estan en la otra tabla,

pero esto no validaria si en tu tabla infolote hay valores repetidos entre si, lo cual solucionarias con un distinct

```
     SELECT DISTINCT Programa FROM galaxyfx_produccion.infolote 
        WHERE (Status = 'NO PAGADO') 
           AND (Autorizado = 1) 
           AND galaxyfx_produccion.infolote.Programa NOT IN 
(SELECT programa_cortador.Programa from programa_cortador)
```

Comment: yo creo que en este caso eso no aplicaría, ya que los programas nunca se repiten, y excelente, me funciono de maravilla, entonces solo una duda. ¿Qué es lo que hace la instrucción después del NOT IN?
Si le entendí, compara las tablas o que onda?

Comment: La clausula NOT IN en sus parentesis debe contener un arreglo, donde si encuentra una coincidencia de Programa con el arreglo devolvera false . es decir el select nos devolveria ese arreglo.

Comment: entonces los programas que inserto en la otra tabla ya no los muestra cuando se vuelve a ejecutar la consulta, verdad?

Answer (score 0):

No se que hacen `EjecutarINSERT()` pero sino permiten usar parametro deberias cambiarlo

Puedes validar si existe usando el `COUNT()` y el `ExecuteScalar()` del command

Por ejemplo usar algo como esto

```
private void MeterProgramas()
{            
    int cant = programa_cortador_cantidad();

    if (cant == 0)
    {
        var res = get_infolote();  

        foreach (DataRow row in res.Rows)
        {
            int programa = Convert.ToInt32(row["Programa"]);

            if(programa_cortador_existe(programa))
            {
                programa_cortador_insert(programa);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Para lo cual separas la funcionalidad en metodos

```
public int programa_cortador_cantidad()
{
    string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM programa_cortador"; 

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
    { 
        conn.Open(); 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
        return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 
    } 
}



public DataTable get_infolote()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
    { 
        conn.Open(); 

        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM galaxyfx_produccion.infolote 
                    WHERE (Status = 'NO PAGADO') AND (Autorizado = 1)"; 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(dt);
    } 

    return dt;
}


public void programa_cortador_insert(int programa)
{
    string sql = @"INSERT INTO programa_cortador(Programa) VALUES(@programa)"; 

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
    { 
        conn.Open(); 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@programa", programa)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
}

public bool programa_cortador_existe(int programa)
{
    string sql = @"INSERT INTO programa_cortador(Programa) VALUES(@programa)"; 

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
    { 
        conn.Open(); 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@programa", programa)
        int cant = Convert.Toint32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 

        return cant > 0;
    } 
}
```

Eso de tener metodos genericos no es buena idea